# ag-grid (8.2.0) not rendering some rows

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

Whenever I call `setRowData()` to add rows that exceed the number of rows that can be displayed by the grid div unless scrolling, some rows are not added to the DOM. Even if I scroll to the bottom of the grid, they don't show up.

If I resize the grid, these missing rows magically appear.

I notice the row count and the `getRenderedNodes()` count are not the same.

I tried calling `refreshView()` from a setTimeout but it didn't work.

Is there an option to force rendering on all row? or at least to make them show up when I scroll?

Comment: Hi Mate..did you manage to fix this issue yet?I am stuck with a similar issue where AG-GRID is not rendering all my rows.

Comment: No, unfortunately I was not able to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I've had encountered a similar issues with adding new rows after the grid has already rendered.  Instead of calling `setRowData()` try calling `addItems([..])` instead where the array passed to `addItems` are the new rows that you're wanting to add.  For whatever reason, this isn't in the grid api documentation, but you can read more about it at https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-insert-remove/#gsc.tab=0

With that function by default, it won't automatically refresh.  Try leaving the refresh as default at first and then refresh if the issue persists.